# Can Set () method in the Repository having reference to my DBcontext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, generics, model-view-controller

I have a simple generic repository.

In this Repository, I have a generic DBContext and thats means its not specific to my appliktion.

The generic DbContext are still able to access my DBcontexts Entites, such

```
Context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity)
```

Do the method Set() here geting reference to my webapplikationens DBContext, or what is happening ?

Full Code:

```
    public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        TEntity Get(int id);
        void Add(TEntity entity);
    }

...

    public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        protected readonly DbContext Context;

        public Repository(DbContext context)
        {
            Context = context;
        }

        public TEntity Get(int id)
        {
            // Here we are working with a DbContext, not PlutoContext. So we don't have DbSets 
            // such as Courses or Authors, and we need to use the generic Set() method to access them.
            //Returns a non-generic DbSet instance for access to entities of the given type in the context and the underlying store .
            return Context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
        }

        public void Add(TEntity entity)
        {
            Context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
        }
    }
.................................

    public interface IAuthorRepository : IRepository<Author>
    {
        Author GetAuthorWithCourses(int id);
    }
..

    public class AuthorRepository : Repository<Author>, IAuthorRepository
    {
        public AuthorRepository(PlutoContext context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        public Author GetAuthorWithCourses(int id)
        {
            return PlutoContext.Authors.Include(a => a.Courses).SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
        }

        public PlutoContext PlutoContext
        {
            get { return Context as PlutoContext; }
        }
    }
..


    public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        IAuthorRepository Authors { get; }
        int Complete();
    }
...

  public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private readonly PlutoContext _context;

        public UnitOfWork(PlutoContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
           Authors = new AuthorRepository(_context);
        }

        public IAuthorRepository Authors { get; private set; }

        public int Complete()
        {
            return _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
    }


...

        public class Repository<Entity> : IRepository<Entity> where Entity : class
        {
        protected readonly DbContext Context;

        public Repository(DbContext context)
        {
            Context = context;
        }


        public void Add(Entity entity)
        {
            Context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Set()` will return any entity that is registered in the context subtype you inject into the repository.

Comment: If we imagine that I inject my generic Repository with this Entity "House".

This line,Context.Set<Entity>()Find (id); will in my Repository bee translated to:

Context.House (). Find (id);

But Context her is still generic and should´t I convert  it to My application DBContext?

Comment: The argument `DbContext context` is just a *compile-time* type, the *actual* type of the parameter isn't changed. But why don't you just try? Usually seeing it, helps understanding it.

Comment: I've tried it and it works. I just dont understand WHY it's working.

Answer (score 0):

The argument DbContext context is just a compile-time type, the actual type of the parameter isn't changed.